# How practical is an unicycle on uneven surfaces?

Tags: safety, unicycle

From my experience riding a bicycle the fact that a bicycle has two wheels makes it rather easy to ride over minor obstacles like minor cracks in the road. Segway also looks promising in this aspect although it's rider's guide is full of "don't do this [usually refers to trying to ride over an obstacle in wrong way] otherwise your Segway looses grip of the terrain and you fall big time" phrases.

Now a unicycle has only one very tiny spot of contact with the road. How does one ride over obstacles on a unicycle?

Comment: A pedestrian has only two tiny points of contact with the ground, how could one ever move over obstacles?

Comment: @moz: Well, a pedestrian can step over obstacles, while the unicycle has to roll over them.

Comment: A better alternative to the segway exists in the self balancing unicycle. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kzy1uqFDeqo&feature=related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose one could legitimately ask how "practical" a unicycle is, since only a very small number of people can be said to have actually mastered riding the things....

However, I have seen folks with amazing skill, and even off-road unicycles equipped with knobby tires...The riders negotiating rocks, logs, and typical off-road obstacles.
So...Rider skill obviously a big part of this.

I think the unicycle in motion would be reasonably stable over most "pavement"-type obstacles; cracks, seams, that sort of thing.

Comment: Agreed, I've seen a few kids on mountain unicycles that are better riders than others with 2 wheels!

Answer (score 10):

If the word "practical" ever enters your vocabulary, then you really have no business messing around with unicycles.

Unicycling over rough terrain [can definitely be done,](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm8QU-eKrLA) but it ain't easy.

Comment: Oi! Unicycles are eminently practical. For a fairly narrow range of tasks, but very suitable for those. Compared to similar-sized folding bikes (the Strida, say) they're more robust, at least as fast and can carry more weight.

Comment: How exactly do you propose unicycles can be faster than geared bikes? To hit 25 km/h on a large 28 inch wheel unicycle you'd have to pedal with cadence of about 180.

Comment: A folding bike is, in fact, much slower than a unicycle. Unless you unfold it before riding.

Comment: @ttarchala: a bike like the strida is definitely faster downhill, if you are a light person and the road is smooth. But the frame is very flexible and the gearing is very low, and it is almost impossible to ride one uphill. But it does fold to the size of a unicycle, where something more rideable does not. To hit 25km/h on a strida you'd need protective clothing and no sense of fear.

Comment: Of course, with a unicycle when you want to get on the bus you simply step off the uni and onto the bus, while the folding bike rider is still trying to untangle themselves from the bike prior to folding it.

Comment: @moz: I appreciate your deadpan humor.

Comment: Here's [another nut case](http://youtu.be/sV_w3CodBcw) doing stuff on one wheel I can't do with two. But I agree, this stuff isn't easy and "practical" isn't the word for it.

Comment: Check out Kris Holm (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sV_w3CodBcw&feature=related). One of the great extreme unicyclers. I had a friend who was into this sort of stuff and I tried it out a few times. The great thing about unicycling is that it's very easy to bail out. Usually when your bike goes down you go down too, but if you feel you're falling on a unicycle you can often land on your feet.

Answer (score 3):

Mountain Unicycling (MUni) has become increasingly popular since it came on the scene in the early 1990s. To cope with the terrain, MUni unicycles are better built than regular unicycles often with double-bolted seat-post clamps and a brake. Riders usually wear helmets and shin/wrist guards due to the high likelihood of a UPD (unplanned dismount).

The most famous MUni rider has to be [Kris Holm](http://krisholm.com/) who nowadays has his own range of unicycles and equipment.

[Here](http://youtu.be/tKDpGugVsR4) is an example of what is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unicycling around town will encounter a lot of uneven surfaces or abrupt changes. Wheel size plays a big role in how much of a problem it is, depending on the bump or divot. For instance, I find it difficult to ride a 20 inch freestyle uni in the downhill to uphill transition from a road up to a sidewalk sometimes, especially if it's steep. Move that to a 36er and I barely notice (in part because inertia carries you through). I'd say little cracks are generally unnoticeable on either. Hurray pneumatic tires!

A lot of going over an obstacle (when you're not jumping), is anticipating it and getting the wheel just a little bit in front of you. Once you're comfortable riding a uni and the uni is a little bit ahead of you you'll notice that inertia will catch your back foot and pull you back up onto the uni, I find. So, if you hit an obstacle with some speed but preparing to brake it'll push the wheel up and amplify catching your back foot to pull you up and forward.

If you think about it, if you're ahead of the wheel and you hit an obstacle, you're either falling forward or your shoulder is going to have to pull the unicycle faster than you're going to fall (somehow). This could work if you're also jumping instead of just rolling over the obstacle, though, as you could swing your uni in the jump.

As for drops, you just need to see them and not pedal while you're falling. Again it's more difficult with smaller wheels (since you can hit the deadzone quickly if your wheel is free, and usually short cranks limit your torque), but it calls more for attention than skill. A random 1 inch divot is not hard to ride over, but you'll probably fall off if you don't see it coming and adjust your pedaling cadence (on a small wheel especially, but unexpected falls can make you fall off bigger wheels too). Dropping off a curb is not a big deal if you keep your feet on the pedals and somewhere near neutral or carry some speed.